# How to convert array in Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a problem with converting an array to an Object in JS.

I received data from Back-end like this(below image) and I want to change detec_time array data to Object.

In detect_time data, the first element is "time" and the second element is "its value"
ex) 0: (2) [18, 1794] is 18 o'clock and its value is 1794

[image: data]

- Issue: Converting data.detect_time array to Object
- What I expected : [ {10: its value} , { 11: its value }, ... {24: its value} ]
- Attempt:
  1) if statements --> add key & value in newObject called weekendDataObject
  floatingPopulationPerWeekendData.detect_time which means data.detect_time what I mentioned above

```
let weekendDataObject = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    let timeIndex = 10;
    if (
      floatingPopulationPerWeekendData.detect_time &&
      floatingPopulationPerWeekendData.detect_time[i][0] == timeIndex
    )
      return (weekendDataObject.timeIndex =
        floatingPopulationPerWeekendData.detect_time &&
        floatingPopulationPerWeekendData.detect_time[i][1]);

    timeIndex++;
  }
```

2. making a new array of time and adding its value to new Object

```
 const arr = [floatingPopulationPerWeekendData.detect_time &&
    floatingPopulationPerWeekendData.detect_time[0][0]]

  const dataObject = {
    // floatingPopulationPerWeekendData.detect_time &&
    //   floatingPopulationPerWeekendData.detect_time[0][0] : floatingPopulationPerWeekendData.detect_time &&
    //   floatingPopulationPerWeekendData.detect_time[0][1]
    arr[0] : floatingPopulationPerWeekendData.detect_time &&
      floatingPopulationPerWeekendData.detect_time[0][1]
  }
```

Both of them didn't work what I expected... Could you help me how to convert it to an Object? I really appreciate your help!

edit 1:

```
  var response = floatingPopulationPerWeekendData;
  var objects_from_array = response.detect_time.map(dt => {
    return { time: dt[0], value: dt[1] };
  });
  console.log(response);
  console.log(objects_from_array);
```

I assigned the responsibility as the data getting from the back-end and when I check the console. I checked the data as well. However, I got this error message "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')" So, I tried

```
var objects_from_array = ([] && response.detect_time).map(dt => {
    return { time: dt[0], value: dt[1] };
  });
```

and

```
var objects_from_array = (response && response.detect_time).map(dt => {
    return { time: dt[0], value: dt[1] };
  });
```

but both of them didn't work.

edit 2:

I tried to follow up another solution and here is what I trying to do

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${BASE_URL}/notice/business/detected/${shopID}`, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf8",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("access")}`,
      },
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (data) {
          let timeIndex = 10;
          let weekendDataObject = {
            timeIndex: "",
          };

          for (let i = 0; i < data.detect_time.length; i++) {
            if (data.detect_time && data.detect_time[i][0] === timeIndex) {
              weekendDataObject.timeIndex = data.detect_time[i][1];
              console.log(weekendDataObject);
            }
            timeIndex++;
          }
        }
      });
  }, []);
```

When I trying to do like this I got this result
[image]

it should be time number instead of timeIndex string and I have to got 15 arrays but I only get a few of them. I guess my logic is something weird but I am not sure which part is wrong...

eidt 3: Adding what I expected the result ==> - What I expected : [ {10: its value} , { 11: its value }, ... {24: its value} ]

Comment: This question has a problem. You are saying `both of them didn't work what I expected` what is what you expect?? It would be helpful if you could be clearer about this.

Comment: @Gass I expected that there is an array with an object such as [ {10 : its value} , {11: its value} , ... {24: its value}] lie this!

Comment: Why do you need to add a condition if you want an object with all the data?

Comment: @Gass To be honest, I am just.. trying to solve the problem. When I trying to solve this issue, I thought I need some condition

Comment: I see, I'm just trying to understand the logic and see if I'm missing some info. You don't need a condition because you need to add all of the data inside a new object. There is not filtering required, which makes it even easier.

Comment: The order is different from the source, which is `18` then `12` then `19` etc. Can I assume you want to sort the array by the time as well?

Comment: @Gass Oh I remembered why I add some conditions, the reason why is I want to add data in order(sorting). I received the data randomly I mean sometimes the first could be 18 o'clock and 13 o'clock something like that. However, I don't need a condition for now because I can access the data through key if I convert array to object

Comment: @3limin4t0r yeah you're right

Comment: @Gass If you don't mind, how do I do that what you mentioned without condition?

Comment: I just did, check out my edit.

Comment: First create the object and then sort it out

Comment: @3limin4t0r Yeah. You're Correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, mainly you need to add sorted data to a new object. So firstly we `sort()` the data and then using a loop that iterates through the length of the sorted array we build the object, like so:

```js
let myObject = {}, i;

const data = {
  detect_time: [ 
    [10,1794], [160,1503], [25, 1434], [100,1714], [13,503]
  ]
}

let sortedArr = data.detect_time.sort((a,b) => {return b[0] - a[0]});

for (i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i++){ 
  myObject[sortedArr[i][0]] = sortedArr[i][1] 
}

console.log(myObject);
```

### Suggestions

I can see some problems with your code, for instance you are declaring a variable inside the loop and then summing up this variable, which wont, because the loop is always declaring it as `10` at the start. It should be outside.

You can also make your code cleaner by changing your long variable names for smaller ones. For example `floatingPopulationPerWeekendData` you could change it to `data` and your code would look like so:

```
let weekendDataObject = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    let timeIndex = 10, data = floatingPopulationPerWeekendData;
    if (
      data.detect_time &&
      data.detect_time[i][0] == timeIndex
    )
      return (weekendDataObject.timeIndex =
        data.detect_time &&
        data.detect_time[i][1]);

    timeIndex++;
  }
```

Also, if you are comparing variables is better to  use `===` rather than `==`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to map every array inside detect_time to an object? Something like:

```
  var detect_time_array_of_objects = backendResponse.detect_time.map(dt => {return {time: dt[0], value: dt[1]}});
```

the resulting structure will look like :

```
[
    {
         time: 18,
         value: 1794
    },
    {
         time: ....
         value: ....
    },
    ...
]
```

sorry I didn't test out the code. Here's a working snippet:

```js
var response = { detect_time: [ [18,1794], [19,1503], [14, 1434]]};

var objects_from_array = response.detect_time.map(dt => {return {time: dt[0], value:dt[1]}});

console.log(objects_from_array);
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for trying to help me out!
I tried to follow up your solution like 
var detect_time_array_of_objects = floatingPopulationPerWeekendData.detect_time.map(dt => {time: dt[0], value: dt[1]});
Howeverr, I got this error message " expected ;" and highlited red in value : here

Comment: oh and I think the data set up should be like "{time: dt[0][0], value: dt[0][1]}" right? because I got the two elements in array

Comment: I've just created an snippet, somehow the {} were getting interpreted as the function body, instead of a literal object, therefore the error.

Comment: FYI: If you want to return an object directly in an arrow function you can wrap it in `()`. So `{return {time: dt[0], value:dt[1]}}` would become `({time: dt[0], value:dt[1]})`

Comment: @PabloRecalde Could you check my edit1 part? I am not sure why I got this error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')" even when I check the console.log of response...